# Icono android deformado

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una app en la que el icono se muestra deformado solo en dispositivos Samsung.

[image: iconos deformados]

He añadido en el manifest la línea:

`<application> <meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.icon_container.has_icon_container" android:value="true"/> </application>`

y se ha solucionado de manera parcial. En algunos con versión R o Q se muestra bien, aunque en otros no, siendo ambos Samsung y con la misma versión de Android. Esto le dice a los dispositivos Samsung que no rodee los íconos con un círculo.

Los iconos se obtienen de las carpetas mipmap, cada una de las imágenes con el tamaño correspondiente al tipo de densidad para adaptarse a la resolución de cada dispositivo.

¿Porque salen deformados los iconos?

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Escribeme al correo osdway@gmail.com, yo te ayudaré.

Comment: Hola @Osdward por qué no respondes mejor aquí mismo a su pregunta en lugar de que te escriba a tu correo, así no funciona el sitio, saludos.

Comment: @jorgesys Lo hare, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero borra todos los cambios que hayas hecho y luego haz esto:

```
 Abrir Image Asset Studio(Click derecho en la carpeta drawable,
 new Image asset) puedes agregar un ícono de selector mediante los 
 siguientes pasos:

En el campo Icon Type, selecciona Launcher Icons (Legacy Only).

Selecciona un Asset Type( y, luego, especifica el recurso en el campo que 
aparece a continuación:

En el campo Clip Art, haz clic en el botón.

En el diálogo Select Icon, selecciona un ícono de material y haz clic en OK.
 
Haz clic en Next.

Haz clic en Finish.
```

Comment: Gracias Osdward's. La doy por buena ya que me ha servido para poder dar solución a mi problema. Yo venía haciendo los iconos con la web de https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/. Aunque he de decir, que al hacerlo con Image Asset Studio, en Icon Type he seleccionado Launcher Icons (Adaptive & Legacy), seleccionar la imagen y finish. Gracias  a tu respuesta he podido dar luz a este problema.

Comment: Me puedes consultar para lo que quieras a confianza crack.